# Can Illustrator export an artboard and have it ignore paths that extend into it from other artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, artboard, clipping-mask

I’m working with a design that essentially looks like a mosaic of tiles, like this:

[image]

I’ve written a script that splits this single-artboard graphic into individual artboards that retain the position of the original block. You can then use the built-in SVG export tool to export all or some of the blocks.

Many of these blocks contain graphics that have a clipping mask applied to hide the elements that extend outside of the block’s boundaries. Problem is, if I export “block g” when “block h” has hidden paths that extend *into* “block g,” then ““block g” will be exported with the “block h” data in tow.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File` > `Save for Web` and make sure that the `Clip to Artboard` box is checked off.
This will save it and crop out the borders automatically.

Comment: I’m exporting as SVG and don’t think that’s possible with Save for Web, which is a legacy tool.